# create and add QMenu to QToolButton via Designer

Tags: qt-designer, qtgui

i wonder how it is possible to define popup menus in Qt Designer and add them to some toolbutton.

i know how this is done in code but i think it have to be possible in designer too. otherwise i would have gui defining code in my class that is a bit ugly.

please can somebody give me an advise?

(using Designed 4.8.5)

Comment: There is currently no way to do this within Qt Designer.

Comment: @ekhumoro it seems that you are right :-(